# Difference between GNU and ICC compilers : command line warning #10370: option '-std=c++11' is not valid for C compilations

Tags: c++11, gcc, intel

I am having a hard time compiling a bit of c++ code using intel compiler, while GCC compiler does the job without errors.

Consider the following main function:

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_func_data.h"
int main()
{   
    my_func_data dataFunction;
    dataFunction.vec.push_back(1);
    dataFunction.vec.push_back(2);
    dataFunction.vec.push_back(3);
    dataFunction.vec.push_back(4);

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%f\n",dataFunction.vec[i]);
    }

 return 0;
 }
```

where my_func_data.h is a structure that has to be in a separate header file (for the purpose of demonstrating the issue).

```
#ifndef my_func_data_H_
#define my_func_data_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

typedef struct 
{   
    std::vector<double>vec;
} 
my_func_data;
#endif
```

Now I load two compilers and try to compile the two functions using each.

1st using gnu compiler:

```
module load compiler/gnu-6.2.0
g++ -std=c++11 Main.cpp  my_func_data.h -o main
./main
1.000000
2.000000
3.000000
4.000000
```

Next using intel compiler

```
module load compiler/intel-15.0
icc -std=c++11 Main.cpp  my_func_data.h -o main
icc: command line warning #10370: option '-std=c++11' is not valid for C compilations
my_func_data.h(6): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "vector"
  #include <vector>
                   ^
```

what could prevent ICC compiler from compiling the code?
Moreover, should I embed the structure my_func_data in the main function it compiles and executes all right.

Thank you in advance for any insights!

Comment: Have you looked at the [icc options](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/icc.txt)?

Comment: Thank you for an answer! The `-std=c++11` (which I understand to be the only option here) isn't an issue on its own. It's just the moment I compile the my_func_data as a stand alone header file the compiler throws a warning indicating it is compiling a c-written code & then throws an error for vectors.   Am I misunderstanding your comment? Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`icc` is the C compiler. The C++ compiler is `icpc`.

This is similar to `gcc` vs. `g++`.

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

1. `-std=c++11` is not a valid compiler option. See [the list of valid compiler options](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/icc.txt).
2. icc treats .h files a C source files, not C++ source files.
3. You don't need to use `my_func_data.h` in the command line. Simply use:

   ```
   icc Main.cpp -o main
   ```